# Why my tests aren't run when I use 'mvn cobertura:cobertura'?

Tags: java, maven, testing, junit, cobertura

I'm trying to run one test for my class "Sinus" (used to compute the sinus of a float), but when I try to run this test to generate my coverage report with Cobertura, it doesn't work and I really don't know why !
Dou you have advices or any explanation please ?
(I use the cmd : mvn cobertura:cobertura)

-This is my test:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.Test;


public class SinusTest {

Sinus test = new Sinus();

    @Test
    public static void Sinuszero() {
        Sinus test = new Sinus();
        assertTrue(test.sin(23) == 5);
    }
}
```

And there is the result :

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M5:test (default-test) @ 2 ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.193 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-05-26T11:07:45+02:00
```

So what's the problem ? Any ideas ?
There is my pom.xml below :

4.0.0

```
<groupId>1</groupId>
<artifactId>2</artifactId>
<version>2</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>2</name>
<description>Blank project for Vanilla Spring WebFlux.fn</description>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <start-class>2.App</start-class>
    <spring-fu.version>0.0.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</spring-fu.version>
</properties>


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.fu</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-fu-jafu</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-fu.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>am.ik.yavi</groupId>
        <artifactId>yavi</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.18</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope> 
    </dependency>   
    <dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.11</version>
    <scope>test</scope>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
        <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
        <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        
        <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
         <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>2.5.1</version>
         <configuration>
         <formats>
            <format>html</format>
            <format>xml</format>
         </formats>
         </configuration>
       </plugin>
       
       <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
       </plugin>
     
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Comment: please remove static key word from test method.

Comment: Thank you, I did... but nothing has changed.

Comment: which version of java & maven are you using ?

Comment: I have this in my pom.xml :
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <start-class>2.App</start-class>
        <spring-fu.version>0.0.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</spring-fu.version>
and this : 
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>3.0.0-M5</version>

Comment: @Undefinedz10 How do run your test ? mvn test ? mvn cobertura:cobertura ?

Comment: I'm trying to do both ... but i Have the same result @CodeScale

Comment: @Undefinedz10 Could you share your pom.xml plz ?

Comment: @CodeScale I posted my pom.xml bellow, you can check it.

Comment: No please move the definition above in your initial question please (so update your question)

Comment: Ok i did it @CodeScale

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your test is a `junit4-api` based. But from your pom.xml you have junit5 dependencies.

Removing jupiter dependencies should do the trick.

Regarding cobertura, as you run on java 8 preferably you should migrate to JaCoCo as cobertura with java version higher than 7 is buggy.

Comment: I'm told to do so, by using cobertura, I didn't have a choice ...
Thank you for your help anyway ! It worked ! Even if I have a weird Error in my test that said : 
 SinusTest.<init>:37 Verify Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 99

Answer (score 0):

First of all, read the documentation. The plugin behavior is not a magic.
https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit-platform.html#Provider_Selection
You are using JUnit4 annotations but your POM has two dependencies: JUnit4 and JUnit5. The Surefire plugin takes the preference and ignores JUnit4 runner. The JUnit5 runner of Jupiter is not able to understand JUnit4 annotations in your code and therefore it is not able to find executable sources. You can use JUnit5 Vintage dependency instead of JUnit5 Jupiter.